# Looking for a type that is polymorphic in record fields (static duck typing)

Tags: typescript, polymorphism, record, row-polymorphism

I am looking for a type that is polymorphic in record fields so that it accepts records containing more fields with the constrain that all involved records coincide in these extra fields:

```
type foo = { first: string, last: string };

const o = { first: "Foo", last: "Oof", age: 30 };
const p = { first: "Bar", last: "Rab", age: 45 };
const q = { first: "Baz", last: "Zab", gender: "m" };

const main = (o: foo) => (p: foo) => o.first + o.last

// goal

main(o)(p); // type checks
main(o)(q); // type error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAZg9nKBeKBvWBLATgZ2ALijywwDsBzAGigBsBDPQ4s8qAXwG4BYAKF4GM4pPFEQp0MbIygAiAGIIZ1etJkB5ODCVQ65CIQDMABnbceg4cChhkaTLgKyAQnSzaVjmQCU6AI226+lAALACspgJCIgCOthJSni4AXu4MngBaftp6pAAmEFiEMgC2MhF85lFWxXRktgAUcITwcACUyAB8UPVgzQjtSF1wAHSSDlAA1KLDHry8APTzUORwdDRzPDVkja09rRxQi1CgkFD8ABYQ-ADWOLxbpDv10fuHSyfQBVhwWLxAA)

Is this possible in TS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding generic parameter.

```
const main = <T extends foo>(o: T) => (p: T) => o.first + o.last

main(o)(p); // allowed
main(o)(q); // Property 'age' is missing in type '{ first: string; last: string; gender: string; }'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAZg9nKBeKBvWBLATgZ2ALijywwDsBzAGigBsBDPQ4s8qAXwG4BYAKF4GM4pPFEQp0MbIygAiAGIIZ1etJkB5ODCVQ65CIQDMABnbceg4cChhkaTLgKyAQnSzaVjmQCU6AI226+lAALACspgJCIgCOthJSni4AXu4MngBaftp6pAAmEFiEMgC2MhF85lFWxXRktgA8ACpQEAAewBB5OLAIAHwAFHCEjQCUyL1Q-WDDY0gTcAB0kg5QANSiCx68vDVkgyNTIxxQAPQnUKCQUPwAFhD8ANY4O7Wk+-3RR6fnpHAA7i0sFg4FheEA)

This works because generic type is inferred from first argument (`o`) and resolved to

`{ first: string, last: string, age: number }`

Now second parameter (`p`) type should be assignable to the above.